# changing app root for spring mvc app on tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am working with a sample RESTEasy 2.0 resource on Spring MVC 3.0 and deplying to Tomcat 6. I can get to my resource through http: //localhost:8080/examples-resteasy-2.1-SNAPSHOT/contacts but I would like to access through http: //localhost:8080/contacts or even http: //localhost:8080/myservice/contacts

Is there something I need to change in the way my application is mapped to the path?

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/contacts/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**springmvc-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http: //www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http: //www.springframework.org/schema/context http: //www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http: //www.springframework.org/schema/beans http: //www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    ">
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.jboss.resteasy.examples.springmvc" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <import resource="classpath:springmvc-resteasy.xml" />  <!-- this is included in the resteasy-spring library-->

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**my RESTEasy resource class**

```
@Controller
@Path("/contacts")
public class ContactsResource {
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set these in your Tomcat server.xml.

Add a `<Context>` element within the `<Host>` like below which sets your `examples-resteasy-2.1-SNAPSHOT` as the default web app.

```
<Context docBase="examples-resteasy-2.1-SNAPSHOT" path="" reloadable="true" />
```

This should allow you to access it as http: //localhost:8080/contacts

Set the path to "myservice" like below

```
<Context docBase="examples-resteasy-2.1-SNAPSHOT" path="/myservice" reloadable="true" />
```

should allow you to access it as http: //localhost:8080/myservice/contacts

Comment: Thank you. I will try the server.xml way. My only concern is that Tomcat documentation and others strongly discourage going through server.xml and encourage META-INF/context.xml

Comment: @pastafarian: thats true, but on 6.0 i've not got it to work via META-INF, only server.xml