# Spring MVC project in STS 3.1

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc

Need some help from Spring developers.

I am using STS 3.1 on windows. Created a new MVC project by selecting New > Spring Template Project > Spring MVC project named 'mymvc' and ran it under vFabric tc server. When I point my browser to `http://localhost:8080/mymvc/`, it gives 404 error but works fine when I use the url `http://localhost:8080/app/`.

There is only one application on the server and no url mapping for `/app`  in the project.

Am I missing someting?

Please guide. Thanks.

EDIT

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

One more thing: I have named my package com.mycompany.app and STS launched `http://localhost:8080/app/` instead of `http://localhost:8080/mymvc/` when I ran the project.

Comment: can you post your web.xml please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that app is the last part of your package name. For example I think that you have the following situation: your project is named **myproject** and, inside it, you have a package named something like: **org.blabla.app**

By default STS use the last part of your package name to create the URL of your project, infact you have that the URL: `http://localhost:8080/app/` work well

If you want that your URL is something like `http://local_host:8080/projectname` you have to change the Context Root of your project, using STS\Eclipse you have to do the following thing:

Righ click on your project name (inside the package explorer) ---> Web Project Setting and insert in the context root field the name of your project, deploy again your project and this is all

Comment: An other solution is change the Context Root directly on your server after that you have deployed it. In this case you have to do the following operations:
Right Click on your server (inside the Server View tab) ---> Click Open.
Now appear to you a visual editor related to your server configuration and to your deployed application.
Search a tab named Modules that show all the deployed project. Select your project and click on edit button. Now you can change the Context Root as done in the previuos example

Comment: I prefer the first solution, I prefer have the Context Root that I would directly in STS...but this is personal

Comment: At the end of this personal article I explain this thing. The article is in italian language but you can see the screenshot about these operation: http://scorejava.com/index.php/spring-spring-mvc/corso-spring-mvc-3-1-3-2/29-8-creiamo-un-hello-world-in-spring-mvc-facendo-uso-di-maven

I hope that I have help you

Comment: thanks. This worked. In addition, need to stop the server and clean it before running the project again with changed context root.

Answer (score 0):

You have other solutions to configure a tomcat server for your application
such as [Tomcat default application](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F) or [changing the context in your server.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773687/changing-app-root-for-spring-mvc-app-on-tomcat)