# How to make spring mvc app run under a sub folder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I was only testing my spring-mvc as a root app on top of tomcat 7.0.50, now however I need to run at under a subfolder of the domain, like www.blabla.com/myapp

Unfortunately it does not work: all the resource files are missing and the application tries to redirect itself to root all the time.

How do i configure a spring mvc application to run under a subfolder?

Comment: This link can help you and should work with tomcat 7 also, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem was that all references (including form actions) in jsp pages are absolute (a least with my current configuration) and I had to *c:url* them.

static resources:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

form actions:

```
<c:url var="proceedActionUri" value="/user/mainscreen"/>
<form:form method="post" action="${proceedActionUri}" commandName="user" role="form">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your configuration of your HTTP Server (Apache, Nginx) and it has nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: ok but Tomcat exposes your webapp with an url like http://host:8090/webappname. If you want to expose it on the port 80, you need an http server. Otherwhise I think this post may be relevant for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773687/changing-app-root-for-spring-mvc-app-on-tomcat